# Работа с несколькими полями двух объектов

Tags: java

Суть такова: есть класс Cat, есть два объекта cat1 и cat2, у котов есть переменные (сила, возраст и вес). Нужно создать метод в котором в зависимости от параметров кота мы решим кто победит. 
Чего я не могу понять: в метод я пытаюсь передать двух котов и сравнить их, но передаются только значения первого кота. (от второго как я понимаю ячейка в памяти)
Скрин прилагается. Если будет не трудно, скажите, пожалуйста, где я ошибаюсь и как это исправить.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: код -> текстом, а не картинкой. Неужели сделать и вставить скриншот быстрее, чем скопипастить текст?

Comment: сори, я тут новичок

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вместо

```
public int catPower;
```

напишите

```
public int getPower()
{
  return strength / (age + weight);
}
```

Тогда

```
public boolean fight(Cat aCat)
{  
  return getPower() > aCat.getPower();
}
```

Comment: Это помогло, спасибо. А вообще возможно обойтись без геттера?

Comment: @Makaroni нет, невозможно

Comment: дело не в геттере как таковом, а в том, что "кто-то" должен посчитать силу кота, чтобы ее использовать.. в данном случае это делает геттер